# selecting using sparql based on 'triple does not exist'

Tags: rdf, sparql, triplestore, triples

I need a little help selecting the right triples from my store....

```
<a> a <type/1> .
<b> a <type/1> .
<c> a <type/1> .
<c> a <type/2> .
```

i want to select only elements which are type/1 and not type/2

What is the best way to achieve this using a sparql select query?

am looking for omething like:

```
select ?a where 
{ 
    ?a a <type/1> .
    !{ ?a a <type/2> }
}
```

Thanks,

:)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An alternative SPARQL 1.1 solution is to use `MINUS` e.g.

```
SELECT ?a
WHERE
{
  ?a a <type/1> .
  MINUS { ?a a <type/2> . }
}
```

`MINUS` subtracts solutions that match its triple pattern from the existing matches.

In most cases using `FILTER NOT EXISTS { }` and `MINUS { }` are equivalent but beware there are some corner cases where this is not true - see the [SPARQL 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) for some examples of this.

Answer (score 15):

In SPARQL 1.0 that's a bit tricky:

```
SELECT ?a WHERE {
    ?a a <type/1>.
    OPTIONAL {
        ?a a ?othertype .
        FILTER (?othertype = <type/2>)
    }
    FILTER (!BOUND(?othertype))
}
```

The `OPTIONAL` clause binds `?othertype` for any `?a` that has `<type/2>`, and leaves it unbound for any `?a` that doesn't have it.

The final `FILTER` then selects only those rows where `?a` was left unbound.

In SPARQL 1.1 it's much easier:

```
SELECT ?a WHERE {
    ?a a <type/1>.
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?a a <type/2> . }
}
```

Comment: Changed your SPARQL 1.1 example to use explicit URI in the `NOT EXISTS` as using a variable would also match the `<type/1>` triples the first pattern found and result in filtering out all solutions